# How to read Android Gradle plugin source code in Android studio

Tags: android, plugins, gradle, android-studio

Run gralde sync in Android stuido,it prompted error message  "No such property: packageName for class: com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.GroupableProductFlavor_Decorated".

searched with google,not found a solution.

My android studio's version is 1.0.0,unzip into the folder android-studio.
I found gradle-1.0.0-sources.jar in folder android-studio\gradle\m2repository\com\android\tools\build\gradle\1.0.0, how to open the class files in gradle-1.0.0-sources.jar file like shortcut ctrl+shift+t in eclipse.

Comment: post the content of your `build.gradle` file. it's rather an error in your files than in SDK.

Answer (score 3):

Change "packageName" to "applicationId" may help you. In productFlavor, it only has applicationId property , you can download DSL reference about it on this site:http://developer.android.com/tools/building/plugin-for-gradle.html.

As for difference between applicationId and packageName, you can see [ApplicationId versus PackageName](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/applicationid-vs-packagename)